# Express 3.x req.params is an object with square brackets?

Tags: express

I have a POST handler:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router)

app.post('/api/auth/:service', function(req, res) {
  console.log('req.params', req.params);
  ...
```

When I print req.params I get something odd:

```
req.params [ service: 'webui' ]
```

It looks like an object, but it's got square brackets.

What is `req.params`?

According to http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#req.params :

```
This property is an array containing properties mapped to the named route 
"parameters".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `JSON.stringify()` drops all the "parameter" properties of arrays, leaving only an empty array.

As `JSON.stringify()` was part of the logging process, it confused me.

Example:

```
$ node
> var a = [];
undefined
> a.foo = 'foo';
'foo'
> a
[ foo: 'foo' ]
> JSON.stringify(a);
'[]'
```